# layout errors building github personal site with jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have been trying to put together my own page at [meredithhu.github.io](http://meredithhu.github.io). As you can see, at this point, only the Home page is displaying the correct layout, all other pages' (if you click through the tabs on home page) layouts are off... And I couldn't figure out why and how to fix it...

All the codes are here: https://github.com/meredithhu/meredithhu.github.io.

I defined layouts in the _layouts folder, apparently only the default.html is working... but aren't all others defined the same way? how could none of the other ones work?

Could anyone give me some hints how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `link` tag from `default` layout

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
```

to this ->

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the styles loading, if you just use `href="css/main.css"` then the browser will use the current level as the base URL, this is why it works for the base url, but not for any other deeper category/page, in `_layouts/default.html` change the CSS line to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{site.baseurl}}/css/main.css">
```

Also, in `_config.yml`, there is a wrong parser, remove the line `markdown: shengli` so the website loads properly.